# Efficiently render checkerboard in HTML

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, optimization

I'm working on a project where I'd like to be able to render a giant checkerboard pattern on a component in a webpage. It'll have variable size, but probably no more than 100x100 cells, and each cell will be a square with side len 100px.

Here's an image to kind of show what I want:

[image: (Checkerboard pattern)]

Don't worry about the border/background, I just need to optimize those little squares.

Currently, I'm using `<svg>` with `<rect>` elements like so:

```
<svg style={{width: canvasSize*100, height: canvasSize*100}}>
  {Array.from({length: canvasSize}, (_, c) => {
    return Array.from({ length: canvasSize}, (_, r) => {
      return (
        <rect
        x={c * 100}
        y={r * 100}
        width={100}
        height={100}
        fill={calcFillColor(r, c)} />
      );
    });
  })}
</svg>
```

I'm worried this will get slow for large grids. Is there a faster way to implement it? It would be a bonus if I could control hover/click events, like brightening cells that are hovered over, storing clicked (selected) cells to a state, etc.

I'm using React if that's useful information, although this will be mostly HTML anyways (unless theres a faster way)

Edit: After looking around I also found a solution that uses <tr> and <td> - would that be faster than svg?

Comment: I'd consider flattening the rectangles' data to a flat array and mapping over it – you're also missing `key`s, which is making things slower than they should be.

Comment: Further, you might consider virtualizing the grid (i.e. only render the elements that will be visible); you're looking at something that's going to be 10,000 x 10,000 pixels all in all?

Comment: Use.a [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns)

Comment: "After looking around I also found a solution that uses <tr> and <td> - would that be faster than svg?" Good question. And you can add CSS Grid to that -- so, having a div for each cell and then style them using CSS Grid.